# New Cat stuck under kitchen cabinet

Tags: cats, behavior, new-pets

My daughter brought home a shy 5 yo fixed female. At the last owner's home Chloe was really sweet and friendly. She got her in the house and without thinking she opened the crate (she was concerned as she had vomited just moments from home.) Chloe was gone in less than 15 seconds. She found a hole under the kitchen cabinet and will not come out! I know she is scared to death!

I tried offering treats, and she lashed out with paws and teeth.

So we set up food, water and a litter box. We are coming up on 48 hours with nothing to drink or eat, and no voiding.

What am I supposed to do?

I tried dry, moist, pot roast. I am afraid she is going to die in there. She is in the noisiest part of the house.

Comment: Do you know someone who can partially disassemble your cabinets without damaging them too much so you can get at the cat? 48 hours without food and water is not good. If you get the cat out please take her to a vet immediately. Can you post a picture of the hole and surrounding cabinetry?

Comment: Can the previous owner coax her out?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, get some help with disassembling the cabinet, as it is dangerous for cats to go without food and water for more than a day, and it gets progressively more dangerous as time goes.

If the cat does not start eating within a very short time after getting her out, you need to take her to a vet immediately.

It is always a good idea to take a new cat to the vet within a short time after you get it, for vaccines and a checkup, and so the vet knows you and your cat if any emergencies should ever happen.

Answer (score 1):

Before disassembling the cabinet, try using a broom stick or other object to push/pull her out and *back into her carrier*. Then you can release her again in more appropriate room to begin settling in to her new home, such as a quiet bathroom with her litter box and food.